# LabVIEW - How to shorten the path of a .net Refnum

Tags: labview

I am currently having the issue, that my VI can't read a .dll File, because the path is too long.
Is there any way to shorten the path of a .net Refnum?

Comment: What is your current path? Could you move dll to another location, so path will be shorter?

Comment: Thank you for this question. I just looked at my path and noticed a %, I replaced it wit a _ and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

My Path had a percent symbol in it.
I replaced the symbol with an underscore and now it works. It seems like, that when it comes to opening a .dll file, LabVIEW doesn't like %.